# Numberguessing class and client

Tags: java

I am trying to code a number guessing class and client.

The issue/problems I am having with this class/client is that my number guess either ends up too high or too low and in top of that it loops the number twice when it should once.

```
Number generated from 0 to 100. Wanna take a guess(enter 0 to give up)
Let's take a guess: 
50
40
Your guess is too low
```

What possible change can I make to improve the overall loop or change.

Here is my code for anyone that wants to look at it.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class NumberGuess
{

  private Random generator;
  private int Number;


  int intGuess= (1 + (int)(Math.random()*100));
  int numGuess=0;
  boolean isGuessCorrect=false;

  public NumberGuess(){
  }

  int numguess;
  public int guess(int guessIn){
    int numguess=guessIn;
    if(numguess>intGuess){
      return 1;
    }else if(isGuessCorrect){
      return 0;
    }else{
      return -1;
    }
  }

  public int getNumberofGuesses(){
    return numGuess;
  }

  public boolean gameIsComplete(){
    if(isGuessCorrect){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }

  public void reset(){
    intGuess=(1 + (int)(Math.random()*100));
    numGuess=0;
    isGuessCorrect=false;
  }
}
```

Client class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberGuessclient{
    public static void main(String[] args){

      NumberGuess game1=new NumberGuess();
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);            

      int quit=1;
      while(quit != 0) {
        System.out.println("Number generated from 0 to 100. Wanna take a guess(enter 0 to give up)");
        System.out.println("Let's take a guess: ");

        int guess1= scan.nextInt(); 

    while((guess1 != 0)||(!game1.gameIsComplete())) {
            guess1 = scan.nextInt();
            if (game1.guess(guess1)==1){
              System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
            }
            else if(game1.guess(guess1)==-1) {
                      System.out.println("Your guess is too low");
                }
                else {                      System.out.println("guessed in " + game1.getNumberofGuesses() + " tries");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Enter 1 for new game, 0 to quit: ");
            quit = scan.nextInt();
            if(quit==1){
                game1.reset();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

source code for more ELABORATION if not clarified above.

NumberGuess Class:

The NumberGuess class will facilitate a number guessing game.  The constructor should generate a random number, saving the number in a private class field.  The class should also define a method which accepts a "guess", compares the "guess" to the randomly generated number, and returns one of the following:

```
•   -1 the guess was less than the secret number
•    0 the guess matched the secret number
•    1 the guess was higher than the secret number
```

Determine whether other methods, constructors or otherwise, would be useful for this class.

The Java API defines a Random class for generating random numbers.  The class can be reviewed in the API or in your textbook beginning on page 250.  Consider limiting the range of the random number.  For instance, a number between 0 and 100.

Client Application:

The client application allows the end-user to play the number guessing game.  Below is a sample run.  Your application does not need to match. 
I'm thinking of a number between 0 and 100. Can you guess it?

```
Take a guess: 50
Your guess is too high
Another guess? (Y or N): y
Take a guess: 25
Your guess is too high
Another guess? (Y or N): y
Take a guess: 10
Your guess is too low
Another guess? (Y or N): y
Take a guess: 15
Your guess is too low
Another guess? (Y or N): y
Take a guess: 18
Your guess is too low
Another guess? (Y or N): y
Take a guess: 20
Congratulations! You correctly guessed the secret number in 6 tries.
```

Comment: wait how do I do that, I do accept answers but don't have a clue how to do it here.

Comment: @blake for a question you've asked under the answer's score (the number to the left of the answer) there is a check mark you can click on to accept that answer.

Comment: OH I see. I have accepted some of the questions I have posted yesterday. So that's how you accept.

Comment: Now accept the best answers from your more previous questions, and you'll make all happy.

Comment: Ok - to the code! Why do you use Math.random and util.Random, both? Use util.Random and generator.nextInt (100); for the Game.

Comment: so I am suppose to use one or the other then.

Comment: so I should only save the number/integer in the private field then, got it.

Comment: @twain249: Why do you suggest the opposite of me? Imho, nextInt (100) is more easy to use than fiddling with the modulo operator.

Comment: @userunknown because I misread his comment as saying that he had to use `Math.Random()` my mistake.

Comment: alright so the change would be import.java.util.random at top, and then randomgenerator() 100 for the int guess method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a bit of things that you can change, for instance:

- There's no need to call `game1.guess(guess1)` more than once every loop.
- The completion method is quite long...
- You should call `scan.nextInt()` before entering the while loop...
- I'm assumming the last output was manually generated, because you never increment  `numguess`
- The `guess(int)` method doesn't work...

I'm not usually one to do homework... but (I'm having a good day...!):

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberGuessclient {

    private static final String[] ANS = {
        "Your guess is too low\n", 
        "guessed in %d tries\n", 
        "Your guess is too high\n"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            NumberGuess game = new NumberGuess();
            System.out.println("Number generated from 0 to 100. Wanna take a guess(enter 0 to give up)");
            System.out.println("Let's take a guess: ");

            while (!game.isGameComplete()) {
                System.out.format(ANS[game.guess(scan.nextInt())+1], game.getNumberofGuesses());
            }

            System.out.println("Enter 1 for new game, 0 to quit: ");

            if (scan.nextInt() != 1) {
                System.out.println("Bye!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

class NumberGuess {
    private static final Random RAND_GENERATOR = new Random(System.nanoTime());
    int intGuess = RAND_GENERATOR.nextInt(101);
    int numGuess = 0;
    boolean isGuessCorrect = false;

    public int guess(int guessIn) {
        numGuess++;
        if (guessIn > intGuess) {
            return 1;
        } else if (guessIn == intGuess) {
            isGuessCorrect = true;
            return 0;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public int getNumberofGuesses() {
        return numGuess;
    }

    public boolean isGameComplete() {
        return isGuessCorrect;
    }
}
```

Now one comment: as I recall the "fun" of this game was that you should always "guess" the number in at the very most 10 tries, you could implement that...

Comment: @Riley Lark was it 7 tries for 100 numbers? I can't remember! jejeje I believe this game would be much more fun to implement as a reciprocal of this example, something like, you think a number and the program does the "guessing"... =P